# Ubuntu Server 22.04 without systemd networking on startup

Tags: networking, server, systemd, netplan

I sometimes want to start my little server device without networking --- in particular if I don't have a network currently connected.  (the device is moved around.)

is there a `systemctl` to disable the networking service?  I would then restart it by hand when I need it.  I first tried to `systemctl stop` network, networking NetworkManager, etc., but none of these seem recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server 22.04 is using netplan. Default renderer is `networkd` when using netplan under Ubuntu (Server).

Check your configuration files in:

```
ls /etc/netplan/
```

Edit or cat the files within this directory if you wish. To get the current configuration use:

```
sudo netplan get
```

Applying the setting goes via:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

To validate your new IP, gateway and DNS use: `ip addr` for your IP info and `ip route s` for your gateway and `resolvectl status` for your DNS.

To finally answer your question. If you do not configure the interface in netplan, the network interface will be down by default. See: https://netplan.io/faq#deconfigure-an-interface. To manually remove the address use: `ip address del <address> dev <interface>`

More info in the docs: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-tutorial/#showing-your-current-netplan-configuration (there is also an official "homepage" at: https://netplan.io/).